# Invalid name entered in UDF with VBA for Excel

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I am making a simple UDF that checks if a given country is a member of the OECD. I have two inputs:

1. Excel cell containing the name of the country
2. Input containing the first cell of a column containing all the OECD countries.

The function compares the content of the cell `Candidate` and of the column of `countries` via a loop. If the candidate name does not match with any of the OECD countries, in the end the function classifies it as a non-OECD country.

My code is like this:

```
Function OECD(Candidate, Countries)
    Dim Candidate As String
    Dim Countries As String
    OECDCountry = Countries 'Variable that changes at every iteration, I compare the name of the candidate to this
    For i = 1 To 34     
        If Candidate.Value = OECDCountry Then
            OECD = 2                 
        Else: OECDCountry = Countries.Offset(i, 0)
    Next i

'If the column next to the candidate name, where I am running this function, is still empty, record the country as non-OECD

    If Candidate.Offset(0, 1) <> 2 Then OECD = 1                
End Function
```

However, when I try to use the function, I receive the following error message while selecting the second input:

> The name that you entered is not valid. Reasons for this can include:
>
> -The name does not begin with a letter or an underscore
>
> -The name contains a space or other invalid characters
>
> -The name conflicts with an Excel built-in name or the name of another object in the workbook

Why do I receive this error message and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have duplicate names in your scope.  You ask for variables `Candidate` and `Countries` to be passed to your function as arguments, and then you declare variables with identical names in the function itself.  Those can't be identical names, which is probably causing part of your issue. You then also try to use `Candidate.Value` when you tried to `Dim Candidate As String` and String variables don't have a .Value property (though the passed argument could if it was passed as a cell reference).

Comment: you should consider using the second parameter `Countries As Range`, will make your **UDF** code a lot simpler

Comment: And you should declare `OECDCountry` to be a `String`.  And you will need to declare your UDF as being `Volatile` so that a change to the column listing all the countries will allow your UDF to be reinvoked.  And have you considered using `VLOOKUP` to do everything without the need for a UDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I must say that I think that the OECD countries is an example of static data in that it does not change very often.  I would store the data on a sheet somewhere and then upon first request read it into a cache using a Scripting.Dictionary and then one can use the Exists method.  Here is my solution

```
Option Explicit

Private mdicRunTimeCacheOECDCountries As Scripting.Dictionary

Sub DevTimeSetup_RunOnce()

    ' ___          _____ _           ___      _               ___           ___
    '|   \ _____ _|_   _(_)_ __  ___/ __| ___| |_ _  _ _ __  | _ \_  _ _ _ / _ \ _ _  __ ___
    '| |) / -_) V / | | | | '  \/ -_)__ \/ -_)  _| || | '_ \ |   / || | ' \ (_) | ' \/ _/ -_)
    '|___/\___|\_/  |_| |_|_|_|_\___|___/\___|\__|\_,_| .__/_|_|_\\_,_|_||_\___/|_||_\__\___|
    '                                                 |_| |___|                                           http://www.network-science.de/ascii/
    '* just some code to set up a sheet with some data as OP supplied none
    '* so that anyone can play with this problem
    Dim rngOECD As Excel.Range
    Set rngOECD = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(7, 1))
    rngOECD.Value2 = [{"USA";"UK";"Germany";"France";"Italy";"Japan";"Canada"}] 'not full OECD, just G7
    rngOECD.Name = "OECDCountries"

End Sub


Private Function GetRunTimeCacheOECDCountries() As Scripting.Dictionary
    If mdicRunTimeCacheOECDCountries Is Nothing Then
        Set mdicRunTimeCacheOECDCountries = New Scripting.Dictionary

        Dim rngOECD As Excel.Range
        Set rngOECD = Sheet1.Range("OECDCountries")

        Dim rngLoop As Excel.Range
        For Each rngLoop In rngOECD
            mdicRunTimeCacheOECDCountries.Add rngLoop.Value2, 0
        Next

    End If
    Set GetRunTimeCacheOECDCountries = mdicRunTimeCacheOECDCountries
End Function



Public Function OECD(Candidate) As Long
    OECD = VBA.IIf(GetRunTimeCacheOECDCountries.Exists(Candidate), 1, 0)
End Function
```

and call from worksheet with a cell formula like this

`=OECD("UK")`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was more difficult than I expected but now I think I understood